# set_access_control on azure storage gen2 throws permission error despite connected using storage key

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-databricks, acl

I am attempting to set the acl of an azure storage gen2 directory using python in databricks. It is throwing an error. I am using azure-storage-file-datalake package installed on my cluster from PyPl.
I am using python version 3.9.5 (default, Nov 23 2021, 15:27:38)

I do this to connect using storage account key:

```
account_key = '***'
account_name = '***'

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
    "https",
    account_name
), credential=account_key)
```

```
containerName = 'mark-test-fs'
```

```
filesystem_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(containerName)
```

This runs without error. I am then able to get the access control peoperties of the directory:

```
directory_client = filesystem_client.get_directory_client('folder_1')
a = directory_client.get_access_control()
for key,value in a.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Among those properties are:
owner $superuser
group $superuser

When I attempt to apply a new acl, it throws an exception:

```
acl = 'user::rwx,'  \
    'group::r-x,' \
    'other::---,' \
    'mask::rwx'
change_result = directory_client.set_access_control(acl)
```

The exception contains:

```
*(InvalidOwner) The owner or group is not valid.*
*RequestId:\*\*\**
*Time:2023-03-29T19:45:06.7785008Z*
*Code: InvalidOwner*
*Message: The owner or group is not valid.*
*RequestId:\*\*\**
*Time:2023-03-29T19:45:06.7785008Z*
```

I have reviewed a lot of the microsoft doc on this python library and can see nothing that explains this. The code is pretty simple and I have triple checked it. It closely follows the sample code supplied with the azure-storage-file-datalake python library.

I have done a lot of web searching and looking at microsoft doc for this, and I cannot see why this does not work. I am connecting using a storage key and the directory is owned by superuser. This error does not indicate what owner or group is invalid.

I am able to do these sorts of things using powershell, but would like to implement in databricks for convenience. Any help is appreciated. I can open a microsoft ticket, wondering what part of azure I should do this in.

Answer (score 0):

> **I reproduce the same thing in my environment. I got this same error.**

[image]

To resolve this issue. Follow this [MS_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-acl-python#set-acls).

It has detailed information about how to set and replace ACL in the storage account. I followed the same thing in my environment and was granted access to permission access to storage account gen2.

**Sample code for ACL access. Follow below steps:**

> **Step1:**

**First  execute the code below code, when you execute the code , you will get object id . use the `Object ID` of the group**

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

# Set the account key and name
account_key = '<access_key>'
account_name = 'vamblob'

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
    "https",
    account_name
), credential=account_key)

containerName = 'pool'
filesystem_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(containerName)

directory_client = filesystem_client.get_directory_client('/')
a = directory_client.get_access_control()
for key,value in a.items():
    print(key,value)
```

[image]

[image]

> **Step 2:**

**Use the object Id change and update the permission like below:**

```
 def manage_directory_permissions():
    try:
        file_sy = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="inputdata")

        dir1 = file_sy.get_directory_client("/")
        
        acl = dir1.get_access_control()
        print("Before: ",acl['permissions'])
        new_dir_permissions = "user:xxxxxxxxad33d:r-x,user:7144xxxxxxxx-xxxdf2da1d1:r-x,group::rwx,mask::rw-,other::r--"
        
        dir1.update_access_control_recursive(new_dir_permissions)
        
        acl = dir1.get_access_control()
        
        print("After",acl['permissions'])
    
    except Exception as e:
     print(e)


manage_directory_permissions()
```

[image]

For more information **refer** this [GitHub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-datalake/samples/datalake_samples_access_control_recursive.py).

Comment: Thank-you for your attention to this. I spent a lot of time with that microsoft page you linked to and I am not able to identify how my code is not compliant with the specifications in the document.

I tried your sample code and it worked. I changed it from an update to a set_access_control_recursive(acl) and that worked. What is not working is the non-recursive set method or function. My customers have permission schemes that cannot be addressed in their entirety with recursive setting, and I need to be able to set the acl for a specific directory in a non-recursive way.

Comment: I believe the api is not behaving as documented. I have opened a ticket with microsoft. I note that I have been able to perform these activities using the powershell interface, but I would like to get it going in databricks for a variety of reasons.